# Retrieving array class name

Tags: java, arrays

I have I problem.

In a method I receive a general Object as parameter and I have to retrieve the name of the class

```
public void myMethod(Object o)
  String className = o.getClass().getName();
  ...
}
```

It works, except when i give to the methods arrays.
For example if a pass to the method an array of double (`double[]`), `getClass().getName()` returns me `[D`

How can I retrieve something like `double[]`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[D` means an array of doubles. Check [this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) for an explanation on class names. Why would you like something like `double[]` instead?

Comment: +1 for the link. Never saw that before, learned something new!

Comment: @Fortega I need double[] because it is more clear than [D, I thought that [D could be a non unique identifier. Anyway `getCanonicalName` returns double[]

Comment: A reason for needing `double[]` is if you're creating JavaDoc links.

Answer (score 5):

Simple name of the class is what you are looking for:

```
System.out.print(new String[0].getClass().getSimpleName());
```

and the result well be:

```
String[]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give using the wrapper class, you get '**[Ljava.lang.Double**'

```
Double[] d = new Double[10]
```

d.getClass().getName() gives you [Ljava.lang.Double

Comment: @lucaghera: Anyways,as you said, getCannonicalName returns you double[]