# What is the meaning of clojure output in repl when evaluating this line: (class (byte-array [(byte 0) (byte 1) (byte 2)]))?

Tags: clojure, arrays

It just prints the following:
[B

Is this garbage or should it mean something?  I realize that byte-array is creating a primitive array so maybe garbage is expected since there is no class per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM uses `[` to indicate an array, and what follows is the class of the component type. For the primitive type `byte`, that is represented as the single letter `B`. See [Retrieving array class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011067/retrieving-array-class-name) for one discussion (of many) on this topic.