# How do I express an class literal for an Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

For an ordinary class, I can write `String.class`.

But how do I do this for an array class, including array of primitives?

I can of course  do  as follows, whether for arrays of primitives or of objects.

`(new byte[0]).getClass()` 
and 
`(new String[0]).getClass()`

But is there a more direct way?

Comment: `String[].class`, `int[].class`

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011067/retrieving-array-class-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392160/about-java-get-string-class-from-string-class-what-if-string-class-is) interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is using the .class.

Examples:

```
int[].class
Long[].class
```

These will do exactly what you need.